# Dealing with different size images in a xib for iPhone5 versus iPhone4?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, ios6, iphone-5

The previous posting on here about migrating to iPhone 5 only mention adding a new sized launch image*
and maybe using AutoLayout if need be.

But I have a few xibs where there is a background image which fills up the whole of the screen (maybe minue the navigation and tab bar, depending upon the view). To support iPhone 5 I will now need different images for the different screen size, how is this dealt with in the xib or elsewhere?

(*incidentally what do you do if the app doesn't use a launch image?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](http://redth.info/get-your-monotouch-apps-ready-for-iphone-5-ios-6-today/) a link that will actually help you. Save the launch image, iOS doesn't automatically pick the right image if you put in a "-568h@2x.png" at the end of the file name. There are a couple of helper methods mentioned in the [above link](http://redth.info/get-your-monotouch-apps-ready-for-iphone-5-ios-6-today/) that will make your job easy.

I have adopted the code in the links I mentioned above and here's the helper function for Obj-C:

```
-(BOOL) IsTall
{
    return ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 1136);
}
```

A little category-writing would help too.

```
@interface NSString (Special)
-(NSString*)correctImageNameForiPhone5
@end

@implementation NSString (Special)
-(NSString*)correctImageNameForiPhone5
{
    if([self isTall])
            return -imageNameAppendedWith_-568h@2x.png_-; //Do the correct NSString magic here
    else
            return -originalImageName-;
}
@end
```

Finally, when you are accessing the UIImage object:

```
NSString *filename = @"backgroundImage.png";
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[filename correctImageNameForiPhone5]];
```

The assumption here is that you would have all your iPhone5-specific image file names ending with "-568h@2x". This code sample is definitely not gonna work if you just drop it into your project, but you get the idea. It needs some NSString fixes.

Comment: This is doing it programatically, so xibs with backgrounds can no longer be used?

Comment: If iOS can't handle automatic resizing based on naming convention, I don't see any other option. Although I'd love to know if there's a way out!!

Comment: There is another way to handle taller images programatically. https://github.com/gaj/imageNamed568