# app compatibility with iphone 5 screen size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect iPhone 5 (widescreen devices)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices)

Do any adjustments need to be made for an app started in development prior to the iphone 5 in order for them to work on the iphone 5's larger screen?

If so, what are these changes, or where can I find what to change?  google hasn't been too helpful so far.

Thanks

Comment: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+5+screen), it's also the first result in googling "iphone 5 screen +stackoverflow"

Comment: thats not what i was googling...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the `Default-568h@2x.png` launch image, follow the steps outlined in this post:

[How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

If you are having issues with the images being used INSIDE the app, and you want to support iPhone 5 and pre-iPhone 5 devices, use this:

[Dealing with different size images in a xib for iPhone5 versus iPhone4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753718/dealing-with-different-size-images-in-a-xib-for-iphone5-versus-iphone4/12754158#12754158)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a default launch images with 640x1136px named `Default-568h@2x.png` to support the iPhone 5 screen.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to have a 640x1136 launch image (with `-568h@2x.png` suffix) to make it compatible with the iPhone 5, but to fully make use of the larger screen, there are a many ways to do it. I find the easiest way to do it is to make two separate storyboards, making a new one for the iPhone 5, while maintaining the one you have already used for the iPhone 4S, 4, etc. Using two storyboards removes the necessity for AutoLayout; enabling AutoLayout, it is good to note, also removes iOS 5 compatibility. Use the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536689/xcode-4-5-how-to-pick-storyboards-at-launch) to get started.

Comment: However, like jeffdgr8 says, if your app is made up of tableViews and scrollViews and such, I would stick with his "resize" approach using one storyboard. My suggestion is aimed at an app that uses a more customized interface

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your app views are laid out, you may not need to make too many changes. If you have views that resize and are anchored correctly, such as scroll views or table views, they will expand to fill the additional space on the iPhone 5 screen. You need to add an additional launch image for the new screen size too.

Answer (score 0):

the iphone 5's screen is taller so you'd need to have images with a resolution of 1136x640 also included in your images folder. (add -568h@2x at the end of image's filenames)

also, everytime you will adjust your sprites and everything else that goes on the screen, you will need to account for the iphone 5 separately, just like you account for the ipad and the iphone (non retina and retina).